# Spring: List gets reloaded many times on refresh

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I wanted to display a table from the database to jsp using spring mvc. When I refresh the page , the table gets reloaded again and again. I need the table to be displayed only once even after the table gets refreshed. Could anyone please help me to understand why the same data gets populated repeatedly and how to stop it from happening?

**JobsDAO:**

```
package com.sample.dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.sample.bean.JobsBean;
    import com.sample.util.ConnectionProvider;

    public class JobsDAO {

        static Connection c;
        static PreparedStatement ps;
        static ResultSet rs;
        static List<JobsBean> jobsBeans = new ArrayList<JobsBean>();

        public List<JobsBean> jobs() {

            try {

                c = ConnectionProvider.getConnectionForJobs();
                ps = c.prepareStatement(
                        "select name,age,salary,designation from jobs");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {

                                if(rs.getInt(2)<=50){
                                JobsBean mBean = new JobsBean();
                                mBean.setName(rs.getString(1));
                                mBean.setAge(rs.getInt(2));
                                mBean.setSalary(rs.getInt(3));
                                mBean.setDesignation(rs.getString(4));


                                jobsBeans.add(mBean);
                            } else if (rs.getInt(2)>50){
                                                JobsBean mBean = new JobsBean();
                                mBean.setName(rs.getString(1));
                                mBean.setAge(rs.getInt(2));
                                mBean.setSalary(rs.getInt(3));
                                mBean.setDesignation(rs.getString(4));


                                jobsBeans.add(mBean);
                            }


                        }

                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    ps.close();
                    c.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return jobsBeans;
        }
    }
```

**JobsService:**

```
package com.sample.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.sample.bean.JobsBean;
import com.sample.dao.JobsDAO;

public class JobsService {
    public List<JobsBean> getJobs() {
        List<JobsBean> jobs = null;
        JobsDAO jobsDAO = new JobsDAO();
        jobs = jobsDAO.jobs();
        return jobs;
    }
}
```

**Jobs (Controller):**

```
package com.sample.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.sample.bean.JobsBean;
import com.sample.service.JobsService;

@Controller
public class Jobs {

    @RequestMapping("/jobs")
    public ModelAndView jobs() {
        JobsService jobsService = new JobsService();
        List<JobsBean> jobsBeans = jobsService.getJobs();

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("jobs");
        modelAndView.addObject("jobsBeans", jobsBeans);

        System.out.println("jobsBeans " + jobsBeans);

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**jobs.jsp**

```html
<html>
<body>

 <c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty jobsBeans}">
   <div id="table-wrapper">
    <div id="table-scroll">

     <table class="table table-hover myStyle" id="myT2" border="1">
      <col width="500">
      <col width="50">
      <col width="200">

      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${jobsBeans}">
        <tr>
         <td>${listValue.name}</td>
         <td>${listValue.age}</td>
         <td>${listValue.designation}</td>
         <td>${listValue.salary}</td>
        </tr>
       </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${empty jobsBeans}">
  No employee has been registered for today.
  </c:when>
 </c:choose>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a static variable

```
 static List<JobsBean> jobsBeans
```

which is added to each time you refresh the page

consider making it un-static and doing

```
public List<JobsBean> jobs() {
   jobsBeans = new ArrayList<JobsBean> ();
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much @Scary Wombat! :)